# Flutter detect when Navigator is ready

Tags: flutter, dart

Working on a Flutter app, I am handling deeplinks with a SDK for which I am given a listener that I must handle as soon as the app starts, therefore in the `main()`.

Once a deeplink is received, I must navigate to the proper screen, based on the parameters passed along the deeplink data.

Since I receive the deeplink in the main function, I am detached from the Context of the app, therefore to access the `NavigatorState` I used a navigation singleton with a `GlobalKey` passed to my `CupertinoApp`'s `navigatorKey`. I later use this key to retrieve the `NavigatorState` and call push. (instead of `Navigator.of(context)...`.

However, if opening the app from a deeplink, it is very likely that the `navigatorKey` does not contain anything (yet).

How can I detect/wait until the Navigator is ready ?

As of right now my approach is to add a `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` in my `App`'s `initState`, that resolves a promise to indicate when the `GlobalKey` pointing to the `NavigatorState` can be used... I'm sure there is a beter way to achieve this.

Comment: Just set the `initialRoute` for your `MaterialApp` with the value from your deep link and it will navigate to that route when it builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this i make the initialRoute as a Loading screen and execute all my logic inside it , that way i can have different initialRoutes and i don't have to worry about not having MediaQuery, or Navigator, or even ThemeData.

However the question specifies a way to know if the navigator is available, for this i would use the `builder` function of MaterialApp/WidgetsApp/CupertinoApp, it's used to override the navigator altought i use it to add pading and a global background color and even override the navigator widget with a custom one,

```
CupertinoApp(
  ...
builder: (context, child){
  //The navigator is ready
 Future.delayed(Duration.zero,
            () => print(navigatorKey.currentContext)); //We use a delayed since the child needs to be returned first. It's kinda like a hack 7u7 
  return child;
  }
```

Comment: I understand why you want to execute everything in a loading screen. However, I need to attach the navigator to a listener at the app level. I can't do this in the loading screen because it will later on be disposed and I won't receive any updates